# cap v3 rails 4 passenger deploy Web application could not be started because Gemfile not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, rbenv

When we deploy to our server, everything deploys fine, however we get the error "Gemfile not found" right after. At first I thought this was nginx not starting, but if I restart the box, the error goes away and the application works perfectly. We are trying to determine why this is occurring and how to fix it.  As of right now, I am not sure where to begin and nothing I seem to research on the "google" has turned up answers.

**The breakdown of the server setup and deployment:**

- rails 4
- rbenv
- ruby 2.1.0
- capistrano v3
- passenger
- server build with chef

**The Capfile:**

```
require 'pry'
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Includes default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

# Includes tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails/tree/master/assets
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails/tree/master/migrations
#
# require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
# require 'capistrano/chruby'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
# require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

**The deploy.rb:**

```
set :application, 'api'

set :scm, :git
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:PlacewiseMedia/API.git'
set :branch, 'develop'
set :deploy_to, '/home/apps/api'

set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :keep_releases, 10
set :user, 'deploy'
set :use_sudo, false

set :rbenv_type, :system
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.1.0'
set :rbenv_path, '/opt/rbenv'

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart_application do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      spacer("Setting up restart file")
      execute "mkdir -p #{release_path}/tmp ; touch #{release_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
      spacer("Restarting the nginx service")
      execute "sudo service nginx restart"
      spacer()
    end
  end

  desc 'Run Migrations'
  task :update_database do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      within(release_path) do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          spacer("Updating the database")
          execute :rake, "db:migrate", "--trace"
          spacer()
        end
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Create application symlinks'
  task :shared_links do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      spacer("Creating application symlinks")
      execute "rm #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
      execute "ln -s #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
      execute "ln -s #{shared_path}/config/secrets.yml #{release_path}/config/secrets.yml"
      execute "ln -s #{shared_path}/bin/passenger #{release_path}/bin/passenger"
      spacer()
    end
  end

  after 'deploy:updated', 'deploy:shared_links'
  after :finishing, 'deploy:update_database'
  after :finishing, 'deploy:restart_application'
  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
end

namespace :setup do
  desc 'Copy the secrets.yml and database.yml files'
  task config: ['config/secrets.yml', 'config/database.yml'] do |t|
    on roles(:all) do
      execute "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
      t.prerequisites.each do |file|
        upload! file, "#{shared_path}/config"
      end
    end
  end
end

def spacer(desc = nil)
  puts "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------"
  if desc
    puts desc
    puts "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------"
  end
end
```

**The error:**

[image]

**UPDATE 09/25 : 02:10pm PST**

After working with https://hackhands.com/ we discovered that multiple instances of nginx are running as shown:

[image]

I can work to kill the services and restart it but it seems like something may not be configured correctly on the server via chef or our cap deployment.  If I restart the box things work as stated, but we also tried killing the nginx services.  We discovered that works as well.  Our dev ops team is working on this, but we are still perplexed how this has occurred or how to repair it.

**UPDATE 09/26 : 11:06am PST**

> I found where the config comes from on the passenger spinup, if you
>   look in `/etc/service/` you will see the folders for the apps that are
>   on the server. Look at the `run` file in the folder you're interested
>   in and you'll see the passenger config. That fires off a `ruby .bin/passenger start` process, which then fires off the `/tmp` nginx
>   process which is hanging on app restart. I've tried restarting all in
>   different combos, the one that seems to work is killing the nginx
>   process, then running `sudo killall ruby` to respawn the new app...
>   not ideal

Comment: Is it possible that your Gemfile is ignored via .gitignore?

Comment: Sounds like bundler is getting installed to a different PATH/gemset then the rbenv ruby. You're installing ruby to /opt/ruby with rbenv. I would start by ensuring the 'capistrano/bundler' thing installs bundler to a PATH that the rbenv ruby install in /opt/ruby knows about.
e.g. `which bundle`, `which ruby` and either add the path to what rbenv knows about or install bundler differently so that you can guarantee rbenv will know about it.

Comment: @Anlek yes the gem file is coming over correctly.

Comment: @mmay when I run which ruby I get "/opt/rbenv/shims/ruby" and which bundler I get /opt/rbenv/shims/bundler and which bundle
/opt/rbenv/shims/bundle.  thoughts?

Comment: Hmm...well that confirms that my hunch is wrong! I had a similar issue the other day and in my case fixing the PATHs resolved it. Was not using Capistrano, so not sure what kind of magic it's doing here. Maybe confirm symlinks are being set up correctly? Is the Gemfile it's looking for under that path actually there? Sorry can't be of more help!

Comment: the gemfile is local under /current @mmay

Comment: @mmay any ideas with recent updates?

Comment: @Anlek any ideas with recent updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the update our DevOps team did to address this issue revolves around the way passenger spawns nginx. The config that it was using was the older `spawn-lv2` from previous versions, and I changed it to `spawn` for the current version 4. What this seems to do is to stop creating new directories in `/tmp` that were referenced by the runit script but would fail because the old version was still running. Now it looks like the updates are done in the current `/tmp` directory instead, so it doesn't matter if the process is still running.

This update was done to the rackbox default attribute in chef: default["rackbox"]["default_config"]["passenger_runit"]["spawn_method"] = "smart"